# How do I know what my water table is?

Tags: water

Reference a question I [asked](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116539/will-a-french-drain-on-the-outside-of-a-house-keep-water-out-of-a-crawlspace/116570#116570) about a French Drain, and it was mentioned the "Water Table" height.  How do I know what my water table is?

Comment: Dig a deep hole?

Comment: I don't think I understand what it is.

Comment: Dig deeper than the water table and then your hole will eventually fill up with water to the current water table level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would 1) ask your local Building Code office, or 2) ask your local public utilities office (particularly your plumbing inspector), or 3) ask your public works director, (i.e.: local Building project like a sewage treatment facility will have a Geotech report that will give you the water table...for the area where the facility is being built,) or 4) call local architects, or 5) call local CIVIL engineers, or 6) call DEQ office (especially if they issue drain field permits,) or 7) excavation contractors that specialize in the installation of underground utilities, or 8) hire a Geotech engineer.

A Geotech engineer is very expensive. I'd call all the above before I spent a bunch of money on their tests and report. (Where I live, it costs about $4000.)

Comment: It just occurred to me that you may not know what a water table is. It's a point in the ground where everything is saturated with water. That is to say, a point that water cannot go down any further. Where I live, the water table is about 24" down below ground level. It doesn't mean the water is ALWAYS at this level...it just means that it is the highest level that the ground gets saturated in the rainy season.

Comment: That is what I didn't really understand.  Thanks for the information.